# build an array multidimensional from query results

Tags: php, arrays

I have this code that outputs something like:

```
    Array ( 
[0] => 15 
[1] => 13 
[2] => 16 
[3] => 16 

[4] => 10 
[5] => 10 
[6] => 13 
[7] => 13 
)
```

But, i want this structure:

```
    Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [0] =>  15, [1] =>  13, [2] =>  16, [3] =>  16) 
[0] => Array ( [0] =>  10, [1] =>  10, [2] =>  13, [3] =>  13) 
        )
```

This didn't solve : `$score[] = array($score_bd);`. Any idea ?

**php code**

```
$i =0;
        foreach ($arr_user_apply as $val) {
            $new_val = array($val);
            $arr[$i] = array_merge($str, $new_arr_tags_ids, $new_val, $new_id_oferta);

            $sql = $db -> prepare("
                query
                "
            );

            call_user_func_array(array($sql, "bind_param"), $arr[$i]);

            $sql -> execute();
            $sql -> bind_result($score_bd);

            while ($sql -> fetch()) {
                $score[] = $score_bd;
            };

            $i++;
        }
```

Comment: I tried but I can't understand what parts of the original array you want to separate into multiple arrays?

Comment: i can help u please explain the structure more precisely w.r.t i/p

Comment: @rdlowrey the problem is that, at the moment, with the code above there is always one single array. And i need multidimensional arrays depending on the number of foreach cycles. Like [0][0], [1][0], [2][0] and so on

Comment: arr[0][0] = arr[1][0] = ?  What value will it contain?

Comment: I still don't get what the question is and what are the rules for array transformation.

Comment: @Fel do u need structure? Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 15
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 15
        ) ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am not sure if the question is clear, but this works properly to me

```
            $score = array();
            while ($sql -> fetch()) {
                $score[] = $score_bd;
            };

            $new_score[] = array($score);


Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 15 [1] => 13 [2] => 16 ) ) 
[1] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 10 [1] => 13 [2] => 6 ) ) 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to add another dimension to your first array by placing the key value of the key into the new array something like this might work:

```
$firstArray = Array ( 0 => 15, 1 => 15, 2 => 13, 3 => 13, 4 => 16, 5 => 16, 6 => 10, 7 => 10, 8 => 13, 9 => 13, 10 => 6, 11 => 6 );
$newArray = Array();
foreach($firstArray as $key => $value)
{
  $newArray[] = Array($key => Array($value));
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($newArray);
echo "</pre>";
```

EDIT:

if that's one dimension too deep, then just try this:

```
$firstArray = Array ( 0 => 15, 1 => 15, 2 => 13, 3 => 13, 4 => 16, 5 => 16, 6 => 10, 7 => 10, 8 => 13, 9 => 13, 10 => 6, 11 => 6 );
$newArray = Array();
foreach($firstArray as $key => $value)
{
  $newArray[$key] =  Array($value);
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($newArray);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: so do you need to split the array at every 4th key/val pair?  if so, just throw in a modulous into the loop and step to the next key/val pair after each fourth iteration of the loop

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = array ( 0 => 15 ,1 => 15, 2 => 13, 3 => 13 ,4 => 16 ,5 => 16 ,6 => 10, 7 => 10);
foreach($arr as $key=>$value){
    $new_arr[$key][0] = $value;
}
```